# how can i make ~[0] plus to ~[1] in django?

Tags: python, django, web

1. codes:

   ```
   >>> from test2.models import Member_info

   >>> member = Member_info.objects.all()

   >>> member
   <QuerySet [<Member_info: John2>, <Member_info: John1>, <Member_info: John3>]>

   >>> member = Member_info.objects.all()[0]

   >>> member
   <Member_info: gun2>

   >>> member += Member_info.obejcts.all()[1]

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: type object 'Member_info' has no attribute 'obejcts'

   >>> member += Member_info.objects.all()[1]

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Member_info' and 'Member_info'

   >>> member.append(Member_info.objects.all()[1])

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'Member_info' object has no attribute 'append'
   ```

2.How can i append,,,,?

Comment: What does your title mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can append to `list`, but you are trying to append to `Member_info`. Try this one:

```
member = Member_info.objects.all()[0]
members = [member]
members.append(Member_info.objects.all()[1])
```

Comment: Or you can just get `Member_info.objects.all()[0:2]`.

Comment: I want to select which [n] is appended or not appended by using 'if'.

Comment: Maybe, first answer solve my problem. Thanks for your help!